# problem with resizing Polygons with gBuffer in R

Tags: r, leaflet, overlapping-features

I'm working on something and having a little problem.

```
library(tmaptools)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

USA <- getData(country="USA",level=1)
Texas <- USA[USA@data$NAME_1=="Texas",]
texas_projected <- spTransform(Texas, CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))

places <- texas_projected %>% 
spsample(50, type = "random") %>% 
  # build random poisson buffers around them
  gBuffer(width = 4000*rpois(length(.), 4), byid = TRUE) %>% 
  gEnvelope(byid = TRUE) %>% # take their envelope
  gUnaryUnion()

places <- spTransform(places, CRSobj = crs(Texas))

map<- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data = Texas, weight = 1) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = places, weight = 1, 
              fillColor = "yellow", 
              color = "darkblue")
map

places <- spTransform(places, CRS("+init=EPSG:32633"))
places <- gBuffer(places,width=5)
places <- spTransform(places, CRSobj = crs(Texas))


map2<- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addPolygons(data = Texas, weight = 1) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = places, weight = 1, 
              fillColor = "yellow", 
              color = "darkblue")
map2
```

map and map2 are identical, isn't that supposed to be a gain on the width of those green polygons when we plot map 2 (reproduce de code to better understandment)

why is gbuffer not resizing my polygons?

Comment: How about simplifying the problem and taking the pipes out of play. Then you can track each object and perhapse find out where the code may be failing.

Comment: pipes? you mean I should go on each subgeometry? I'm going to try that, but you see, I was trying to avoid doing such a thing because I will work with bigger numbers, and if I solve the problem by checking one by one, my code will eventually take several minutes to run ( if R doesn't crash in the process)